# how to set keyboard control <a-frame>

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I saw a project using the mouse for movement.

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/pj3m4obt/2/][code]
```

I have a question about WASD control on a frame.

How can I move from 1 path to other path using WASD control on a frame?

Comment: This question is not very clear — can you explain (1) what you're trying to accomplish vs what A-Frame [wasd-controls](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/wasd-controls.html) provides, and (2) some code for what you have tried so far?  See also: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i mean, i want add wasd control to that code, u can open matterport.com there can move using mouse also using wasd control. do you know what i mean?

Comment: Instead of `universal-controls="movementControls: checkpoint"`, does `universal-controls="movementControls: checkpoint, keyboard"` do what you want? See [docs here](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/tree/master/src/controls). Is that what you mean?

Comment: keyboard-controls: WASD+Arrow key movement controls, with improved support for ZQSD and Dvorak layouts. yes i thnk like that but where must i put the code

Comment: Previous comment says exactly which code to replace in your JSFiddle.

Comment: no i mean, i can move w/o from path to other path. so wasd control can chnge path instead move the cursor to that path

Comment: What "path"? You need to include much more information in your original question, and really some code attempting to do the thing you're asking about, sorry. By including more information you make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: you can see here 
https://imgur.com/a/fd1FM 
1,2,3 is path
atm, i move from 1 to 2, or 2 to 3 or 3 to 1 using mouse hover, i want change that instead using WASD

Comment: you can open https://matterport.com/try-it/ for example